# PassportJS not recognizing record

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm running into an issue trying to debug why my PassportJS authorization is not working as it should. I tried to add `console.log` to each if/else statement, but nothing is appearing in my terminal. The only reason I know that there is an issue is because I am using the correct credentials for a registered user, but I'm getting the failure redirect after submitting the form. Could this be due to the fact that I'm using a different parameter than 'username' and I'm not setting it up correctly? Do I need to pass the values from the form?

Model Index:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var path = require('path');
var config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/config.js'));
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
});

var db = {}

db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

user.js:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('users', {
    annotation_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    instanceMethods: {
        generateHash: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
        validPassword: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        },
    }
});
    return User;
}
```

Routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var siteRoutes  = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');

/*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/

// Serialize sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  db.User.find({where: {id: id}}).success(function(user){
    done(null, user);
  }).error(function(err){
    done(err, null);
  });
});


passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true,
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField : 'password'
    }, function(username, password, done) {
        //Find user by email
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        //If there is an error, return done
      if (err) { return done(err); }
        //If user does not exist, log error and redirect
      if (!user) {
        console.log('No email')
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
        //If user exists, but wrong password
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        console.log('Password fail');
      }
        //If all credentials match, return user
      return done(null, user);
      console.log('Successful login');
    });
  }
));


/*====  Index   ====*/

siteRoutes.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index.hbs');
});

/*====  Login   ====*/


siteRoutes.route('/login')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/login.hbs');
    })

    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/app',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
    }));



siteRoutes.route('/sign-up')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/sign-up.hbs');
    })

    .post(function(req, res){

        models.User.create({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }).then(function() { 
        res.redirect('/');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
    })

});



module.exports = siteRoutes;
```

Login Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {{> head}}
</head>
<body>
    {{> navigation}}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="/login" method="post">
                <label for="login-username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-username"  name="username" placeholder="username or email">
                <br />
                <label for="login-password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-password"  name="password">
                <div class="login-buttons">
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/sign-up">Don't have an account? Then register here!</a>
            <br />
            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified e-mail as login attribute but used 'username'.

```
User.findOne({ username: username }
```

As I see there is no field named username in User model.

I think, you should change username to email.

```
User.findOne({ email: username }
```